# Python, Human Readable to Byte Conversion

Tags: python

i'm tried to convert human readable form to byte in python. I figured byte to human readable form, but i cannot figure reverse of it.

I tried some codes from stackowerflow but it will not works perfectly, or i could not find the correct ones.

```
@staticmethod
def byte_to_human_read(byte):
    if byte == 0:
        raise ValueError("Size is not valid.")
    byte = int(byte)
    size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
    index = int(math.floor(math.log(byte, 1024)))
    power = math.pow(1024, index)
    size = round(byte / power, 2)
    return "{} {}".format(size, size_name[index])

@staticmethod
def human_read_to_byte(size):
    - I need here -
```

I need def human_read_to_byte(size) function.

Example: input -> 1 GB output -> 1,073,741,824 (in byte)

Comment: One improvement to the question may be to provide some examples.

Comment: just reverse the polarity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you already have a list of sizes, right? Just do the same thing but in the opposite direction:

```
def human_read_to_byte(size):
    size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
    size = size.split()                # divide '1 GB' into ['1', 'GB']
    num, unit = int(size[0]), size[1] 
    idx = size_name.index(unit)        # index in list of sizes determines power to raise it to
    factor = 1024 ** idx               # ** is the "exponent" operator - you can use it instead of math.pow()
    return num * factor
```

Of course, you'll need to build some error-handling into this, but that's fairly simple - you've already done some for `byte_to_human_read()`.

Comment: Thank you @Green Cloak Guy, it will solve my problem.

Comment: probably `float(size[0])` instead of `int(..)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use an approach like the following. A dictionary is used to hold the abbreviation to numeric factor conversion. While the string parsing isn't bullet proof, it can handle multiple or no spaces in the input and also lower case characters.

```
CONVERSION_FACTORS = { "B": 1, "KB":1024, "MB":1048576, "GB": 1073741824, "TB": 1099511627776, "PB": 1125899906842624, "EB":1152921504606846976 , "ZB": 1180591620717411303424, "YB": 1208925819614629174706176}
def human_read_to_byte(size):
    num_ndx = 0
    while num_ndx < len(size):
        if str.isdigit(size[num_ndx]):
            num_ndx += 1
        else:
            break
    num_part = int(size[:num_ndx])
    str_part = size[num_ndx:].strip().upper()
    return num_part * CONVERSION_FACTORS[str_part]
```

As a comment to [@green-cloak-guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56243838/197011) says, you may want [float()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) instead of [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) here. If that's the case, the parsing is a little more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to these question and answers I came up with a code that short and can work with split (1 B) and tight (10KB) formats. Careful, the code may be fragile in some context, my input is very strict.

```
def human_read_to_byte(size):
  factors = {'B': 1, 'KB':1024, 'MB':1048576, 'GB': 1073741824, 'TB': 1099511627776, 'PB': 1125899906842624, 'EB':1152921504606846976 , 'ZB': 1180591620717411303424, 'YB': 1208925819614629174706176}
  if size[-2:] in factors:
    return factors[size[-2:]]*float(size[:-2])
  return float(size[:-1])
```